# Is it legit to use this disconnect this way

Tags: electrical, safety, subpanel

This is more an expert question for the senior users here, i.e., licensed or former electrician, and/or engineer.

I want to replace a rusted out sub panel that feeds 3 circuits at a residential dock with this [Spa Panel Disconnect](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Midwest-Electric-Products-50-Amp-240-Volt-240-Watt-Non-Fuse-Metallic-Spa-Panel-Disconnect-with-GFI-UG412RMW250P/100686230).

Currently the existing disconnect is fed by a 10/3 direct burial and is fused by a 30amp breaker inside the main house The existing disconnect is a main lug type.

After replacing with new disconnect, I will continue to keep it protected by the 30amp breaker inside the main house, but I'd like to back feed, yes you read me right, **back feed** the 50A GFCI and treat it as a main disconnect while utilizing the GFCI protection it provides to protect the smaller branch circuits "down stream" ( pun intended ).

## Update With Pictures

[image]

[image]

Comment: How are you going to feed 50A down a 10-3 cable? 10-3 is generally deployed for 30A circuits and thus you need to protect it with a breaker no bigger than one with a 30A rating.

Comment: Since the dock structure is likely steel, put the GFCI on land, too many dock swimming electrocutions---this is one case to exceed requirements.  It sounds like you plan to feed that sub panel by back feeding the gfci that is preinstalled.  I know for a fact it's not listed for that, but I don't think it will provide protection in that direction either.  Your last sentence and the fact you're also asking this question scares me... Really badly.

Comment: @Michael Karas, the disconnect is protected by a 30amp breaker inside the main house.  The 50A is being treated as a main disconnect only.

Comment: OK. The words in your question do not make this very clear.

Comment: No problem.  I updated some of the question to help clear that up.

Comment: First what state do you live in the 3 I have lived in have totally different requirements from the NEC. The 2 with tidal changes are totally different than lake homes that float. This may be more important today as the code has changed in the last few years. Some of your text make me wonder, a 30 amp feeder is a feeder to a panel not a back feed.

Comment: @Ed, Georgia.  The lake is lake Oconee and is maintained by GA Power Co.  The existing sub panel is probably 30 years old.  I'm not replacing or extending any wiring.  Just replacing the disconnect.

Comment: Most laws will allow an existing service to be repaired with the same equipment, even if not up to today's code. But if you change the feed it needs to meet current code requirements. Best to double check because I am on the other side of the states now.

Comment: Ed, but I'm not changing the feed.  Just changing the box.  But more to the point was the GFCI downstream protection.  Would that even work?

Comment: Other than the term back feed, if you change from a 30a fused disconnect to a spa panel you may be asking for trouble, spa GFCI's are for personnel protection if I remember the "wet" houses I did in Ca & Or a few years back they had "industrial" type GFCI's that were rated for close to 100ma not the normal 5-6 home spa ones. It has been a few years but that is what I remember and my most recent code books are at work. Check into this before wasting $ on something that will trip by turning a light. Remember a boat with a metal hull can come in and trip a home GFCI with a hot anode.

Comment: Ed, not changing the 30A.  The 30A protection will remain the same in the house.  Interesting comment though on the 100ma ratings.

Comment: Sorry fellow Stack Exchange helpers, a hot anode is a platinum wire with power to eliminate corrosion, similar to zinc on most motors but used in larger boats. I had one on my 24' alumaweld plus zinc because of problems with a smaller AL boat that was in sea water slip. My neighbors hated me!

Comment: May be I should have made this an answer

Comment: I'm confused why you're back feeding the breaker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one major problem with your plan -- GFCI circuit breakers have LINE and LOAD terminals, and thus cannot be backfed according to Code and their Listings (according to [this Square-D document](http://static.schneider-electric.us/docs/Circuit%20Protection/0900DB1001.pdf), you'll fry the trip solenoid if you try).  What I would do instead is change the existing 30A breaker in the main panel out for a 30A GFCI and then backfeed a *disconnect switch* installed in place of the subpanel's GFCI instead of using a backfed breaker or main lugs at the subpanel.  This provides a single disconnecting means for the branch circuits at the subpanel.

Comment: very good reference.  I also found this helpful  http://iaeimagazine.org/magazine/2010/11/16/backfeeding-ground-fault-circuit-breakers/

Answer (score 3):

We're not on the [Code Golf SE](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com), but let's play anyway.

(code golf is a game of making the shortest possible program, with no regard for whether it is understandable.)

[image]

Overcurrent protection is provided by *plain* 15A and 20A breakers *listed for reverse flow*.  The GFCI works in the normal direction and it takes care of GFCI only. I don't know how the busbars are actually arranged, so make sure the 15A breaker drives the lights. This [is a multi-wire branch circuit](http://ecmweb.com/content/multiwire-branch-circuits-can-be-dangerous) and it relies on a [technicality of MWBC rules](http://www.ieci.org/newsroom-and-insights/multi-wire-branch-circuits) - they require ganged shut-off for servicing, but do not, in fact, require ganged overcurrent protection.  I wouldn't actually do it this way since everything works backwards, also the neutral issue. But it works for Code golf.  Now back to reality.

---

[Freshwater shock drownings](http://m.ecmweb.com/content/case-hot-marina) are [serious business,](https://www.ecmag.com/section/codes-standards/dangerous-waters) not least because they often take out multiple family members at once (In fact that is one way they are recognized as not plain drownings).  I'm not one to sit there in my bedroom spending your money, but in this case...

I just **wouldn't use this panel**.  For one thing, it's bottom shelf trash that has nothing to recommend it but price.  I've never heard of this brand and I can't find any breakers for it. `Big Red Flag.` Such a cheap GFCI certainly won't be listed for reverse flow, and I wouldn't look for viable reverse-flow breakers if **cost is a factor**.  Which I assume it is.

I'd go to a proper electrical supply house and price quality 2-space panels of good repute, or 4-8 space if you want expansion room.  You certainly have the wire capacity.  Last I priced them they weren't bad at all.  Consider electrical supply houses in the marina district, because they know this problem and their experience is worth the cost delta, if there even is one, which there often isn't. (at least for the quality.)  After all, if Big Box were cheaper, why would electricians drive past 3 of them to get to an electrical supply house?

You can price whether to go with a GFCI master breaker and individual plain breakers, or no master at all and GFCI individual breakers.  Partly you can price this because they have everything, because that's their business.

As far as rust prevention, I like to put little plywood "houses" around my outdoor electrical boxes, caulked and painted with rubber gaskets around the door ... and make all the cable entrances from the bottom.  I don't imagine salt spray is a problem if you are on a freshwater lake.

Comment: I apologize for leaping to conclusions but you yourself were also unclear about what exactly you are backfeeding.  Also, what would be the motivation: why would you backfeed this dockside area when you have perfectly good grid power available?

Comment: I'll draw a picture tonight. i did not realize this would be so ambiguous

Comment: I know, you see it in your mind but it's hard to say it so precisely that Olympic conclusion jumpers like me get it, lol!  Sorry for adding to that.

Comment: Pictures added.

Comment: I see where I went awry.   You used the jargon term "back feed" rather emphatically, and "generator use" didn't seem right, so I googled it and that's all Google talked about. So I was "off to the races" imagining a generator on a boat, when you mentioned nothing of the sort. Right?

Comment: BTW -- the OP's panel *appears* to have GE guts based on what I've been able to dig up by Googling.

Comment: Also -- the only GF breakers listed for reverse operation are large(200+A), fault powered, molded case industrial GFPE units.  *ALL* MCB GFCI and GFPE devices (even QOs) will fry if backfed -- it's an architectural limitation.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  Well, GE wouldn't be so bad, but I'd worry about the build quality of the rest of it.  Yeah, I can only imagine the price of those, and I wonder about their sensitivity too.  I trust reverse-flow-friendly plain breakers are readily available since they are often used in generator interlocks.

Comment: @Harper -- plain breakers are indeed backfeed-friendly -- anything that *lacks* LINE/LOAD markings on its terminals is tested to work in a backfeed situation.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I had a hunch.   Anyway, making this graphic, I had the  sense that the GFCI breaker is different dimensionally than the expansion slot breakers, suggesting they are from a different system.  Makes me more skeptical of their quality, like they're grabbing the cheapest items they can source, to hit a Home Cheapo price point.  I could be wrong, it may be a trick of the light.

Comment: Amusing, you started off talking about "code golf" but then your answer got quite long. That looks more like my real golf game. I start out with all good intentions of making par and then end up with a quadruple bogie. 

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica -- GFCI breakers *generally* use a somewhat differently shaped frame from their MCB counterparts, as they need extra room inside for the electronics package.  (The only exception I know of at this point in time are the "short body" BR AF and GF breakers)